# ¿Por qué no valida los datos del usuario que recibe Sqlite usando FirstOrDefault en c#?

Tags: c#, sqlite, mvvm, async

Que tal estoy empezando en el desarrollo de aplicaciones móviles para lo cual estoy usando Xamarin, y xamarin forms con arquitectura MVVM y Sqlite.

Tengo hecha la interfaz y validaciones de campos vacios pero cuando quiero validar al usuario si existe o no en la base de datos, no importa que usuario ingrese siempre me dice que existe.

desde el View Model llamo a la función de esta manera

```
    private async void Entry()
    {
        RulesValidation validar = new RulesValidation();
        //Aqui valido los campos vacios e incompletos
        if (validar.ValidarLoginCamps(CiUser, PasswordUser) != 0)
        {
            //aqui llamo a la base de datos, hace la conexion y crea las tablas todo con metodos asincronos
            UserDb user = await UserDb.Instance;
            //Aqui llamo a la validación con la base de datos
            if (user.ValidarUsuario(CiUser, PasswordUser) == true)
            {
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Si", "", "Aceptar");
            }
            
        }
```

La funcion que valida con la base de datos es esta:

```
    public bool ValidarUsuario(string ci, string contrasenia)
    {
        var data = _dataBase.Table<UserModel>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.CiUser == ci);
        if (data != null )
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Cuando uso datos fijos en la validacion con la base de datos funciona, pero cuando hago la consulta a sqlite permite ingresar a cualquier usuario, incluso la BD este vacia.
Me pueden ayudar por favor

Comment: ¿Has visto la documentación de `.FirstOrDefaultAsync` ? Si lo que quieres ver es si hay algún dato con ciertas características, tranquilamente podrías utilizar `.Any(t => t.CiUser == ci)`.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer es validar al usuario que ingresa, con la base de datos; tengo entendido que .FirstOrDefaultAsync devuelve un valor si encuentra, si no te da nulo. gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Lo que recibes en `data` es un `Task` por eso siempre es `true`. Tienes que poner un `data.Wait`;  `var result = data.Resut();` y `result` tendrá recién el resultado de `first..`.

Comment: Es `data.Result;`

Comment: Por otro lado, pensándolo bien no creo que ganes mucho utilizando una lectura asíncrona. Utiliza mejor: `_dataBase.Table<UserModel>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.CiUser == ci);` y no cambias nada más.

Comment: gracias si funciono, y uso lectura asincrona por la documentación que recomienda, quiero probar que tal sale y me esta gustando, gracias de nuevo

Answer (score 1):

Cómo mencioné en mis comentarios `FirstOrDefaultAsync` devuelve un `Task` y por tal razón tu variable data nunca es `null`. Cómo devuelve un task lo que tienes que hacer luego es esperar y cuando termine recuperar el resultado.

```
public bool ValidarUsuario(string ci, string contrasenia)
    {
        var data = _dataBase.Table<UserModel>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.CiUser == ci);
    data.Wait();
   var result = data.Result;
        if (result != null )
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Por otro lado, no creo que pierdas haciendo una lectura sincrona. Quizá con  `FirstOrDefault` es suficiente:

```
public bool ValidarUsuario(string ci, string contrasenia)
    {
        var data = _dataBase.Table<UserModel>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.CiUser == ci);
    
        if (data != null )
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```